# Which of the two code samples is more appropriate

Tags: entity-framework-core

Not sure which one to use in my application...

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
                    .Property(p => p.DateCreated)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .Property(p => p.DateCreated)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CONVERT(date, GETDATE())");
```

Comment: this may be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Opinion-based, but any opinion we can give is nothing-based, because we don't have any context info.

Comment: More appropriate *for what*? Using what standards? How are we supposed to know without more information? You don't even tell us what you're trying to do!

Comment: The first one, because you define column type and then default value

Comment: @Gert Arnold,  Cody Gray,  I simply design my model and database tables. I'm new to fluent API, saw both code  snippets in the EntityFrameworkCore tutorial, and was unsure which one to use...

Comment: @H. Herzl, your comment seems to me quite convincing... Please repeat it as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: `HasColumnType("datetime2")` is redundant. The defaults are different. Inconclusive without knowing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one, because you define column type and then default value.

Comment: This conclusion is based on nothing.